# Adding and Removing User Controls at Runtime, On selection the previous control should get overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a placeholder control and a dropdown on an .aspx page which selects user controls and adds it to the placeholder :

```
 if (dropdown.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            UserControl UC = (UserControl)LoadControl("usercontrolpath");
            placeholder.Controls.Add(UC);

        }
```

I perform all my operations on this user controls (by recreating it on every postback), now I want that when the user selects some other option from the dropdown say:

```
 if (dropdown.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            UserControl UC = (UserControl)LoadControl("Newusercontrolpath");
            placeholder.Controls.Add(UC);

        }
```

then the first user control should be overwritten by this new user control (Older one should dissapear from the page). If I do

```
placeholder.Controls.remove(UC);
```

at the selected index change of the dropdown and then add the new user control then I am getting an index out of bound error when the new control is added to the placeholder.

How can I go about achieving this? 
Please let me know if some more info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Controls.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.clear(v=vs.100).aspx) first:

```
placeholder.Controls.Clear();
placeholder.Controls.Add(UC);
```

You cannot use `Remove(UC)` since that's trying to remove the new usercontrol that is yet not added.

Comment: @Netnetter: where do you recreate the controls on postback? You have to do that in `Page_Init` or (latest) in `Page_Load`. Then add the new control in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList`.

Comment: Am Doing it on Page_Load, its like recreate on Page Load =>Selected index Change => clear() => add()

Comment: @Netnetter: i'm confused since neither `Controls.Clear` nor `Controls.Remove` throws that exception even if the control does not exist. So the cause must be somewhere else which you don't show.

Comment: The error is not getting thrown at Clear() or Remove(), its getting thrown at the Add() of the new User control, after the Clear() or remove() has been successfully executed.